# Prove that the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ is $1$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How does one prove that the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ is $1$?

Comment: You can use the Minkowski bound or show directly that it's Euclidean.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a nice geometric argument, which you can find essentially in Klein's lecture on Ideal Numbers (Lecture VIII in **Lectures of Mathematics**, by Felix Klein, AMS Chelsea Publishing, AMS, 2000).

Consider the lattice $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ in $\mathbb{C}$ ($\zeta_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$). Given $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$, $a\neq 0$. Consider the points in the lattice of the form $(q_1+q_2\zeta_3)a$, and use them to tessellate the complex plane. Then locate $b$, and the closest corner of one of the squares to $b$, $qa$. Then let $r=b-qa$.

Here is a picture which is slightly off, since my lattice here is $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, not $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$, but it should give you an idea; it's taken from the slides for a talk I gave some years ago. It's a bit hard to see, but the small dots are the lattice points; the big dots represent the $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ multiples of $a$, with $a$ the first large dot to the right of the one labeled $0$ and above the horizontal line. (Well, as I said,t he small dots are really in the position of the lattice points of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but you get the idea, I hope). The three labeled dots above zero are (counterclockwise) $a$, $(1+\zeta_3)a$, and $\zeta_3 a$. The dot corresponding to $b$ is circled in red. The blue dot is $qa$, the blue arrow is the vector corresponding to $qa$, and the green arrow is the vector corresponding to $r  = b-qa$. (The "1" at the very bottom of the picture is the page number, so ignore it...)

$\hskip 0.7in$ [image]

How big can $r$ be? The tessellation is by parallelograms whose sides have length $|a|$ and $|\zeta_3 a|=|a|$, so the furthest that $b$ can be from the corner it is closest to is $\frac{|a|\sqrt{2}}{2}$. That is, $|r|\leq\frac{|a|\sqrt{2}}{2}\lt|a|$.  From this it follows that $0\leq N(r)\lt N(a)$.

Thus, for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$, there exists $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ such that $b = qa+r$, and $0\leq N(r)\lt N(a)$. So $N$ is a Euclidean function on $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$, the latter is Euclidean, hence a PID, hence the class number is $1$.

The same geometric argument can be used to show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ are Euclidean, but it breaks down when you get to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, because the size of the rectangles now allows the distance from $b$ to a corner to be larger than the length of $a$ (good thing, too, since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  Are you basically giving a geometric argument for the Minkowski bound which can be used to show that it is Euclidean.

Comment: You can go all the way to (-)11, among the Heegner numbers, in this way.  Using a radicand whose absolute value is $\equiv 3\bmod 4$ allows the "unit-cell" areas to be rendered as triangles instead of rectangles, so the area does not get too big as quickly.

Comment: @Arturo is $r$ the same in $(r+s\zeta_3)a$ and $r=b-qa$?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon We are trying to show that $q$ and $r$ exist, satisfying $b=qa+r$ andn $N(r)\lt N(a)$. We find the closest lattice point, necessarily of the form $qa$, to $b$. Then we define $r$ to be equal to $b-qa$ to ensure that $b=qa+r$;  then we verify that the choice, and how the lattice is defined, ensures that $N(r)\lt N(a)$.

Comment: @Arturo thanks! Got it! $qa$ is defined to be of the form $(r+s\zeta_3) a$ so I was wondering if $r$ was the same as $r= b-qa$ but maybe that was just a coincidence, maybe it was more like $(r_1+s_1\zeta_3)a$. Anyhow, I read the Felix Klein part and what about the angles? How can I convince myself that $|r|< \frac{\sqrt{2}|a|}{2}$, I mean sure since the length of both sides of the parallelogram are |a| if the angles are $90^\circ$, but what if we didn’t have a square? I can guess it intuitively, I was wondering if you had a nice demonstration of this

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: The distance is still bounded by distance to the corners; it's not a rectangle here, since you start with $0$, $1$, $\zeta_3$ and $1+\zeta_3$; you get a parallelogram all of whose sides are length $1$, since $|\zeta_3|=1$. The sides are still $|a|$, because multiplication by $a$ performs a dilation by a factor of $|a|$ and a rotation by $\mathrm{arg}(a)$; the first makes the parallelogram have sides of length $|a|$, the latter does not change the sides, and then you are just tessellating.

Comment: How does it follow from $|r|\leq |a|$ that $N(r)<N(a)$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Please read carefully. What is proven is that $|r|$ is **strictly less** than $|a|$, not less than or equal. Since here the norm is the Euclidean distance, $|r|\lt|a|$ implies $N(r)\lt N(a)$.

Comment: $N(a+b\zeta)=a^2+b^2$, and not $a^2-ab+b^2$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Which part of "the norm is the Euclidean distance" was unclear? It's not the algebraic norm function. It's the Euclidean distance in the complex plane.