# Is $2 \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ a unit, an irreducible element or a prime element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $2 \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ a unit, an irreducible element or a prime element?

Or maybe is not anyone of these?

Comment: It is neither a prime element or an irreducible element in your case. Note that $2=(-1)(\sqrt{-2})^2$

Answer (score 0):

Since the norm is given by $N(a+b\sqrt{-2})=a^2+2b^2$ we have $N(2)=4$, which is different from $1$. Hence $2$ is not a unit. For the irreducible and prime elements in this ring see these duplicates:

[Irreducible elements in  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and is it a Euclidean domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101537/irreducible-elements-in-mathbbz-sqrt-2-and-is-it-a-euclidean-domain)

[Describe the prime elements of the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837016/describe-the-prime-elements-of-the-ring-mathbb-z-sqrt-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The duplicates show that the only units are $\pm 1$, so that $\sqrt{-2}$ itself is not a unit. Now we have
$$
2=\sqrt{-2}\cdot (-\sqrt{-2}).
$$