# Necessary condition for prime numbers in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, complex-numbers

> Let $R=\mathbb Z[e^{i\pi/3}]=\{a+be^{i\pi/3}\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z\}\subseteq \mathbb C$
>
> Prove that if $q$ is a prime element in $R$, then either $q$ ~ $u$ for some $u \in R$ such that $N(u)=p$, where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime, or $q$ ~ $p$ for some prime number $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\neq N(u)$ for all $u\in R$.

(a) Show that $R$ is a Euclidean domain using the Euclidean norm $N(u)=|u|^2$.

(b) Show that if $p$ is a prime number in $\mathbb Z^+$ and $x,y\in \mathbb Z$ with $x^2+xy+y^2=p$, then $x+ye^{i\pi/3}$ is prime in $R$.

(c) Show that if $p$ is a prime number in $\mathbb Z^+$ and $p\neq x^2+xy+y^2$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, then $p$ is prime in $R$.

My attempt : I can't figure out how to show that long division works in $R$, but other than that, I've done parts a till c. I think I have to use parts b and c for the question. b and c involved me 'converting' the problem from one in $R$ to one in $N$ by using the norm. But I really have no idea how to begin. It's an 'or' statement, so I have to assume that $q$ is prime and one condition doesn't hold, then the other one must hold. But I don't know how to actually show this.

Comment: (a) For $N(a) \ge N(b)$, you need to show there exists $q$ such that $N(a-bq) \le N(b)-1$ and hence $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a-bq)= \ldots$ will terminate after a finite time

Comment: You may find the geometrical argument given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23086/prove-that-the-class-number-of-mathbbz-zeta-3-is-1 to be very helpful.

Comment: @AnuragA I don't know what class number means, but I can see that the picture itself is about divisbility. I can see that the picture would be really helpful for that, but my main question is the one at the top.

Comment: See [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Non-examples) : $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$ has more than one ideal class because $2\,\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]+(1+i\sqrt{5})\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$ is a non-principal prime ideal. $1+i\sqrt{5}$ is a prime element with norm $6$. When there is an Euclidean function (thus a $\gcd$ algorithm) any (finitely generated) ideal must be principal.

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I don't know what an ideal class, or a prime ideal, or a principal prime ideal mean :(

Comment: In that case this exercice is way too hard. You are supposed to start with the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and show it is a principal ideal domain to obtain $p = a^2+b^2$ iff $p=2$ or $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: Is there really no other easy way to do it? I mean, the other parts weren't that bad..

Comment: Have you seen similar calculations in $\mathbb Z[i]$ (Gaussian integers)? It may be that the instructor wants you to use that as a model.

Comment: No, this is the first time I've come across a question like this. I asked him how to do it today and it involved noting that the units were the 6 roots of unity and multiplication by them is the same as rotating a complex number by 60 degrees. It also involved one more insight, but I am still in the dark. When I asked him how he expected us to do it, he just smiled and said he didn't.