# How to prove the fundamental theorem of arithmetic for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $d$ be an integer, and define
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]:=\{ a+b\sqrt{d}|a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$
. I have an example that proves that for a value of $d=-5$, the set above with the operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication does not obey the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Notably that
$$6 = (2)(3)=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$$
and $2,3,(\pm1\pm\sqrt{5})$ do not have non-trivial factorizations, ie. they are prime numbers. The proof that $2$ is prime is given by a contradiction. Assuming $2=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+g\sqrt{-5})$ where neither of the factors are $\pm1$, then this implies that
$$4=|a+b\sqrt{-5}|^2|c+g\sqrt{-5}|^2=(a^2+5b^2)(c^2+5g^2)\implies a^2+5b^2=c^2+5g^2=2$$
which is impossible for any integers $a,b,c,g$. So 2 has no non-trivial factors in this set, hence 2 is prime.

The question now is to check if the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is true for different values of $d\in\{ \pm2, \pm3, \pm 11 \}$.

So far from my text, the only example is to prove by counter-example that some element of the set has 2 distinct prime factorizations. So my question here is: should I expect to be able to find counter-examples for all values of $d$? If not, then how would I go about proving that indeed, there is only a unique prime factorization of any element of the set?

Just as a side note, to support a counter-example, like the one above but for the case when $d=2$($\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$), I am having a hard time proving that indeed $3$ is a prime number in this set. Maybe it isn't. Directly using the counter-example doesn't yield the same contradiction. Namely that $a^2+2b^2=c^2+2g^2=3$ works for $a=b=c=g=1$. However, $(\pm1\pm\sqrt2)(\pm1\pm\sqrt2)$ does not seem to actually yield $3$. So you can see I am getting a bit lost here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you suddenly switch from $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt-5\right]$ to $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt 2\right]$?

Comment: @Gary yes i did sorry, I just fixed it.

Comment: for $d=\pm2, \pm3,$ and $\pm 11$, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence PID, hence UFD

Comment: Great! Now reconsider your last paragraph accordingly.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so I guess this proof comes down to proving that each one of those is a Euclidean domain.

Comment: Generally, $Z[\sqrt{d}]$ satisfies the FTA iff it is a PID iff it has class number $1$. For negative $d$ there are finitely many such rings and they are all known, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one). But for positive $d$ it is still an open problem whether there are infinitely many.

Comment: There is a nice geometric proof that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a UFD (in fact, Euclidean). The idea is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23086/prove-that-the-class-number-of-mathbbz-zeta-3-is-1/23094#23094)

Comment: I think you're also misusing terminology a bit: in your example about the factorization of $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, the factors you wrote down are irreducible and that is what you correctly had in mind. However: they are not prime! I recommend to recount the definition of irreducible and prime elements.